# How to sort nodes of XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

There is given order of nodes and I need to sort the nodes of XML according to the given order. The input is a XML file and output is the XML file with nodes ordered according to given list.

XML:

```
<root>
    <M node="C" home="zzz"/>
    <X name="A"/>
    <Z/>
    <Y test="B"/>    
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pSortingValues" select="'Y,X,Z,M,N'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vSortingValues" select=
  "concat(',', $pSortingValues, ',')"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
        <xsl:sort data-type="number" select=
        "string-length(substring-before($vSortingValues,concat(',',name,',')))"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Received Output:

```
<root>
  <M node="C" home="zzz"/>
  <X name="A"/>
  <Z/>
  <Y test="B"/>
</root>
```

Desired Output:

```
<root>
 <Y test="B"/>
 <X name="A"/>
 <Z/>
 <M node="C" home="zzz"/>        
</root>
```

The above XSLT currently only parses the XML without sorting in the required order of nodes: `'Y,X,Z,M,N'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to sort by node name, but the expression `name` is looking for an element called "name". You need to use `name()` to get the name of the node

```
<xsl:sort data-type="number" select="string-length(substring-before($vSortingValues,concat(',', name(),',')))"/>
```

Note, for future reference, you can also use `local-name()` here. `name()` would include any namespace prefix, should namespaces be involved, whereas `local-name()` returns the name without any prefix.